# What is the equivalent JavaScript code for getting a textarea and running it through a program on the local machine without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wsh

Basically I want an equivalent of this in JavaScript:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $comment = "";
    } else {
        $var1 = ($_POST["comment"]);
        $comment = exec("any.exe $var1");
    }
}

<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<textarea id="target" cols="80" rows="4" readonly  tabindex="99">
    <?phpecho $comment;?>
</textarea>
```

I want it so it doesn't refresh the page, so far I've got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function function_one(document.getElementById("source")){
      MyObject= new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
      RunExe(){
      MyObject.Run("file:///C:/path to/any.exe")

     }}
     document.ElementById("target").innerHTML = function_one();}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<textarea id="source" cols="80" rows="4" ></textarea>
<button onclick="function_one()">Click me</button>
<textarea id="target" cols="80" rows="4" readonly  tabindex="99"></textarea>
```

Comment: What does the any.exe do? If you could rewrite it in javascript your suggestion would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for security reasons. If it were possible, then any website could run arbitrary programs on your computer without you knowing, so browsers disallow it.

If you need to be able to run local programs, consider writing a native application instead of a web application.

Comment: Thank you, I looked for another way. Since javascript can't run exec I had to stick with my original script. I was looking through ajax when I came across the parameter <iframe>, which does exactly what I want and is still secure. Thank you for helping.